# Change ownership of a partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, root, users

I have an NTFS partition for sharing files between Windows and Ubuntu, but when I want to modify something into the partition I must do it with `sudo`. In the info in Nautilus, it says that the owner ("propietario") is root. I want to change the owner to be me.

[image: screenshot of permissions dialog in Nautilus]

The letters from the bottom say, "You're not the owner, that's why you cannot change the permissions."

Comment: Translation hiccup: Proprietario = Owner (not *proprietary*, which means *owned by somebody*).

Comment: NTFS is a proprietary Windows file system.  It does not support Linux permissions or ownership.  Perhaps this is where you are confused?

Comment: I also use a common NTFS partition to transfer files b/w my 2 OS but the owner of that partition is me not root. Maybe you are mounting that partition as root, hence the owner is root